# Determining Cell next to Data Validation based on drop down

Tags: excel, vba

So for example let's say we have a Data Validation drop down in sheet Main in cell B2 using Barney, Jack, Moe.

In C2 I want a cell that displays a `number.Sheetname` based on the Data Validation.

```
Barney = 1.Main
Jack = 2.Main
Moe = 3.Main
```

How would I do this?

If I do `=CELL("address", b2)` it will give me `2`

Comment: What is `Data Verification`? Or did you mean `Data Validation`?

Comment: Typo.... Yeah Validation

Comment: Kool, One moment posting an answer. this may take 5 mins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming that `"Barney","Jack","Moe"` is just an example. You may have a longer list? If yes, then for this you have to first create the data validation appropriately.**

For demonstration purpose, I am placing your list G2,G3,G4 and then selecting them and giving them a name.

[image]

Next create the data validation in cell B2 as shown below.

[image]

Put this formula in cell C2

`=IFERROR(INDEX(MATCH(B2,Names,0),1,1) & ".Main","")`

and you are done :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **C2** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(B2,{"Barney","Jack","Moe"},{1,2,3})  & ".Main"
```